# Why “The set X belongs to *A* , since it belongs to each σ -algebra that belongs to *C*“ holds

Tags: measure-theory

Let X be a set. Then the intersection of an arbitrary nonempty collection of σ -algebras on X is a σ -algebra on X .

Proof.
Let  *C* be a nonempty collection of σ-algebras on X, and let *A* be the intersection of the σ-algebras that belong to *C*.
The set X belongs to *A* , since it belongs to each σ -algebra that belongs to *C* .

Why “The set X belongs to *A* , since it belongs to each σ -algebra that belongs to *C*“ holds 
It holds by definition ? Or something I lost that can derive it. 
Does we perform the intersection an of any subsets of *C* can get the set X?

Comment: Let $\{\mathcal F_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be a collection of $\sigma$ algebras on $X$. By definition of $\sigma$ algebra, $X\in \mathcal F_\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in I$

Comment: When you take intersection of a collection of $\sigma-$ algebras you don't take intersection of sets from these  $\sigma-$ algebras. You just take sets that are common to these $\sigma-$ algebras.